# Azure Devops Pipeline Docker Build

Tags: docker, azure-devops, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault, cicd

my question is how to build a docker in the build pipeline with different environments depending on the pull request/branch. I use .net6 and Key Vault + Variable Groups. As I know when the docker builds the image he uses appsetings.json. If I don't want to pass prod settings to this file and I want to override or somehow give settings from Variable Groups to the Docker file or is there another way to make this?

```
trigger:
    - main
    - test
    - development
    stages:
    - stage: Build
      displayName: Build stage
      jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
          inputs:
            command: buildAndPush
            repository: $(imageRepository)
            dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
            containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
            tags: |
              $(tag)
              latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [conditionally assign value to the variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) in YAML pipeline.

For example, suppose there are 4 Docker registry service connections to 4 different Docker registries (**`Registry01`**, **`Registry02`**, **`Registry03`** and **`Registry04`**), and 3 branches (**`main`**, **`test`** and **`development`**) in the Git repository.

The targets are:

- When the build is run for **`main`** branch, the Docker images need to be built and pushed to **`Registry01`**.
- When the build is run for **`test`** branch, the Docker images need to be built and pushed to **`Registry02`**.
- When the build is run for **`development`** branch, the Docker images need to be built and pushed to **`Registry03`**.
- When the build is run for a pull request, the Docker images need to be built and pushed to **`Registry04`**.

We can configure the YAML pipeline like as below:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - test
    - development

variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry01'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test') }}:
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry02'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development') }}:
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry03'
  ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/') }}:
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry04'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build stage'
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: 'Build job'
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: 'Build and push an image to container registry'
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
          latest
```

For the values of other input parameters (**`repository`**, **`Dockerfile`**, **`tags`**, etc..) on the Docker task, you can use the same method to conditionally assign their values. And you also can conditionally assign the **vmImage** of the agent you want to use to run the build job.

For example.

```yaml
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
    vmImageName: 'windows-latest'
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry01'
    imageRepository： 'repository01'
    dockerfilePath: 'Dockerfile01'
    tag: 'tag01'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test') }}:
    vmImageName: 'windows-2019'
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry02'
    imageRepository： 'repository02'
    dockerfilePath: 'Dockerfile02'
    tag: 'tag02'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development') }}:
    vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry03'
    imageRepository： 'repository03'
    dockerfilePath: 'Dockerfile03'
    tag: 'tag03'
  ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/') }}:
    vmImageName: 'macOS-latest'
    dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Registry04'
    imageRepository： 'repository04'
    dockerfilePath: 'Dockerfile04'
    tag: 'tag04'
```